# Using patterns in ReplaceAll to match different symbols

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, rule

I have an expression

```
expr = kb.kpb+kb.kb+knb.knb+kpb.knb+kd.kpd+kd.kd+knd.knd+kpd.knd;
```

and I want to make replacement rules as:

```
{kb.kb->kb^2,kd.kd->kd^2,kb.knb->knb^2,kb.kpb->kpb^2,
 kpb.knb->0,kd.kd->kd^2,kd.knd->knd^2,kd.kpd->kpd^2,kpb.knb->0}
```

Instead of writing down every possible combination, I want it to be general, so I try:

```
rule1 = {k_ . k_ -> k^2, kp_ . kn_ -> 0, k_ . kp_ -> kp^2, k_ . kn_ -> kn^2};
```

but when I run my code, the output is:

```
expr1 /. rule1
(* kb^2+kd^2+knb^2+knd^2 *)
```

the term is `kpd^2+kpb^2` missing.

What is the problem with my replacement rules?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Unfortunately, that is not exactly how patterns work. I suggest you read [Introduction to Patterns](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Patterns.html). Namely, when you write `k_`, this does not mean "any symbol which starts with the letter k", but it means "any symbol, which I will temporarily name with k". That is why, for example, `k_ . k_ -> k^2`, matches and replaces all terms in your expression (try `expr /. k_ . k_ -> k^2`).

Comment: @Domen thanks for your reference. I learn a lot. is there any way to choose variables of my expression by their name in a general mode?

Comment: You can do more complicated rules which look at the string form of your symbol, and then check which letters this string contains. However, a slightly more elegant way is to use a more "structured" version of your variables, for example: `k[b]` and `k[p, b]` instead of `kb` and `kpb` because these are then much easier to match in replacement rules.

Comment: A random example: `k[b] + k[d] + 2 k[p, b] + k[p, b]^2 /. {k[x_] :> k[x]^3, k[x_, y_] :> k[x] k[y]}`

Comment: @Domen thanks to your help. I have a function in my code and kd and kb's are its input argument, when I use the structure that you used, the code gives me some error.   $IterationLimit::itlim: Iteration limit of 4096 exceeded.

Comment: It's difficult to say exactly what is going wrong without seeing the code, but you may try with clearing the variables first, namely `Clear[k, b, d, p]`.

Comment: hi again @Domen. can I use Except in pattern Condition's?  Like S[k[a_, b_], p[c_/; (Except[c==b])]] ;> 0?

Comment: You don't need `Except` in this case, just write the condition. Oh, and you have to put it outside so that it sees b: `(S[k[a_, b_], p[c_]] /; c =!= b) :> 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to solve this problem is to use a more intelligent way of naming variables. Generally, the difference between variables is applied by changing their names, while in Wolfram language, variables can be written as functions and finally treated as a variable. For example, to solve the mentioned problem, the code can be rewritten in the following way to solve the problems completely.

```
expr = Dot[k[b, 4],k[b, p]] + Dot[k[b, 4],k[b, 4]] + 
     Dot[k[b, n],k[b, n]] + Dot[k[b, p],k[b, n]] + Dot[k[d, 4],k[d, p]] +
     Dot[k[d, 4],k[d, 4]] + Dot[k[d, n],k[d, n]] + Dot[k[d, p],k[d, n]];
```

Now it's easy to write a comprehensive replacement rule for it that easily covers all possibilities. While this is not possible in the usual way of naming variables and using patterns.

```
replacementRules = {
      Dot[k[qIn_, vIn1_], k[qIn_, vIn2_]] :> 
        Which[
            vIn1 == vIn2, k[qIn, vIn1]^2
          , vIn1 == 4   , k[qIn, vIn2]^2
          , vIn2 == 4   , k[qIn, vIn1]^2
          , vIn1 != vIn2, 0
        ]
};
```

Answer (score 6):

If I understand the question, then `k1` and `k2` (shown below) are two groups that dictate the outcomes of the dot products.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
expr = kb . kpb + kb . kb + knb . knb + kpb . knb + kd . kpd + 
   kd . kd + knd . knd + kpd . knd;
k1 = {kb, kd};
k2 = {kpb, knb, kpd, knd};

rule = {Dot[a_, a_] /; MemberQ[k1, a] :> a^2
   , Dot[a_ /; (MemberQ[k1, a]), b_ /; (MemberQ[k2, b])] :> b^2 
   , Dot[a_ /; (MemberQ[k2, a]), b_ /; (MemberQ[k1, b])] :> a^2 
   , Dot[a_ /; (MemberQ[k2, a]), b_ /; (MemberQ[k2, b])] :> 0 
   };

expr /. rule
```

> kb^2 + kd^2 + kpb^2 + kpd^2

Comment: thanks, its brilliant. in my expression k and kp and kn are constant and d or b is indicators. so, indicators may change. Can I write the rule which can affect more general? I mean despite of what indicator used; it could dose its work.

Comment: Can you include more indicators to the list `k2`? If you have test cases that can't be handled with this strategy, then you can add those to the post. If you have a different (more general) problem to solve, then you can also ask a separate question. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your first pattern is o.k., it replaces all squares. However, the second one is disastrously. "kp_ . kn_ -> 0" is the same pattern as "x_ . y_ -> 0". It replaces everything by 0. That is why you are getting only square terms.

It is not 100% clear to me what your output should be. I assume that you want: [image]
This can be achieved by:

```
rule = {k_ . k_ -> k^2,
   kb . knb -> knb^2,
   kb . kpb -> kpb^2,
   kd . knd -> knd^2,
   kd . kpd -> kpd^2
   };
expr /. rule
```

[image]